# Connecting a Remote HTML Website and a Remote Database

Tags: html, sql, database

I’m working on an HTML website that requires I use a database. With some help from SQL and Java, I was able to populate a database with information (a .db file, if that helps any). It’s located on my machine and *won’t be uploaded to any online servers*. The HTML website is also located on my machine and *won’t be uploaded on the internet/hosted online*.  Both are located in the same project folder on my machine.

I was wondering if there was a way to connect my database to my website. I’ve seen tutorials recommend using PHP or JavaScript, but they all seem to apply to online databases and websites hosted on the internet. Because this project is just for my own personal HTML practice, I don’t plan on using any online servers for the website or the database.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: which database engine are you using?

Comment: I have [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which database engine you are using (i.e. SQL Server), it might be possible to expose the database as OData endpoint which you can consume directly from your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

there is a sqlite library for javascript called sql.js

https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js